# Why in SWI Prolog, I get the result with `|` sign?

Tags: list, prolog

I have the following code to group sequences of equivalent objects together:

```
pack([], []).
pack([X], [X]).

pack([H, T|TS], [H|TR]):-
    H \= T,
    pack([T|TS], TR).

pack([H, H|HS], [[H|TFR]|TR]):-
    pack([H|HS], [TFR|TR]).
```

My input is:

```
pack([1,1,1,1,2,3,3,1,1,4,5,5,5,5], X).
```

And as a result I get:

```
[[1,1,1|1],2,[3|3],[1|1],4,[5,5,5|5]]
```

Have you noticed `|` sign before the last element in each list? I do not know why it appears and how to fix it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list is a data type that has two type of functors/constants:

- the empty list `[]` which has no arguments; and
- the "cons" `[element|list]`.

As is denoted in the second option, the **second parameter of a cons should be a list**. This can be another cons (and thus recursively further), or an empty list. Nevertheless, Prolog is not really typed, so you *can* use an integer, character,... as second item, but then it is *not* a list.

So now the question is, "*how do we construct such weird list*". In this answer, I used a smaller example to reproduce the error, because it makes things easier:

```
?- trace.
true.

[trace]  ?- pack([1,1], X).
   Call: (7) pack([1, 1], _G1066) ? creep
   Call: (8) 1\=1 ? creep
   Fail: (8) 1\=1 ? creep
   Redo: (7) pack([1, 1], _G1066) ? creep
   Call: (8) pack([1], [_G1144|_G1141]) ? creep
   Exit: (8) pack([1], [1]) ? creep
   Exit: (7) pack([1, 1], [[1|1]]) ? creep
X = [[1|1]] .
```

If we thus pack two elements, something goes wrong. First we call `pack([1,1],X)`.

First the third clause fires, but the `H \= T` item fails. So as a result Prolog *redoes* the call, but now with the *last clause*. In the last clause, we see something weird:

```
pack([H, H|HS], [[H|TFR]|TR]):-
    pack([H|HS], [TFR|TR]).
```

What we see is that we perform a recursive call on `pack/2` with `[TFR|TR]`. So that means `[TFR|TR]` should be a **list of lists**. But the **second clause does not generate a list of lists**, but only a *list of items*. So the error is in:

```
pack([X], [X]).
%%        ^ list of items??
```

So what we need to do to resolve the error, is rewrite the second clause to:

```
pack([X], [[X]]).
%%        ^ list of list
```

Now we have solved that problem, but we are still not there yet: there is also an **type error in the third clause**:

```
pack([H, T|TS], [H|TR]):-
    %%           ^ item instead of a list?
    H \= T,
    pack([T|TS], TR).
```

Again we can simply make it a list of items:

```
pack([H, T|TS], [[H]|TR]):-
    %%           ^ list
    H \= T,
    pack([T|TS], TR).
```

And now we obtain the following code:

```
pack([], []).
pack([X], [[X]]).

pack([H, T|TS], [[H]|TR]):-
    H \= T,
    pack([T|TS], TR).

pack([H, H|HS], [[H|TFR]|TR]):-
    pack([H|HS], [TFR|TR]).
```

We then obtain:

```
?- pack([1,1,1,1,2,3,3,1,1,4,5,5,5,5], X).
X = [[1, 1, 1, 1], [2], [3, 3], [1, 1], [4], [5, 5, 5|...]] [write]
X = [[1, 1, 1, 1], [2], [3, 3], [1, 1], [4], [5, 5, 5, 5]] .
```

**EDIT**:

In case there is only one element, you apparently do not want to construct a list. That makes the problem a bit harder. There are two options:

- we adapt the code such that if such element occurs, we do not add it to a list; or
- we perform some post processing, where we "unlist" lists with one element.

The last one is quite trivial, so lets do the first one. In that case, the second clause should indeed read:

```
pack([X],[X]).
```

Now the second clause should read:

```
pack([H, T|TS], [H|TR]):-
    H \= T,
    pack([T|TS], TR).
```

as well. But the last clause, is harder:

```
pack([H, H|HS], [[H|TFR]|TR]):-
    pack([H|HS], [TFR|TR]).
```

There are two possibilities here:

- `TFR` is a list of items, in that case we simply prepend to the list; or
- `TFR` is not a list, in which case we construct a list.

In order to solve this problem, we can define a predicate:

```
prepend_list(H,[HH|T],[H,HH|T]).
prepend_list(H,X,[H,X]) :-
   X \= [_|_].
```

and then use:

```
pack([H, H|HS], [HTFR|TR]):-
    pack([H|HS], [TFR|TR]),
    prepend_list(H,TFR,HTFR).
```

So now we obtain:

```
pack([], []).
pack([X], [X]).

pack([H, T|TS], [H|TR]):-
    H \= T,
    pack([T|TS], TR).

pack([H, H|HS], [HTFR|TR]):-
    pack([H|HS], [TFR|TR]),
    prepend_list(H,TFR,HTFR).

prepend_list(H,[HH|T],[H,HH|T]).
prepend_list(H,X,[H,X]) :-
   X \= [_|_].
```

Note however that this program will **fail if you want to `pack/2` lists itself**. In that case you better use a post processing step anyway.

Now it constructs:

```
?- pack([1,1,1,1,2,3,3,1,1,4,5,5,5,5], X).
X = [[1, 1, 1, 1], 2, [3, 3], [1, 1], 4, [5, 5, 5|...]] [write]
X = [[1, 1, 1, 1], 2, [3, 3], [1, 1], 4, [5, 5, 5, 5]] .
```

Comment: thank you very much for your explanation and comments! But I wanted to avoid lists in the cases where I have just one element in the list, for example for the `2` and `4`. So, instead of `X = [[1, 1, 1, 1], [2], [3, 3], [1, 1], [4], [5, 5, 5, 5]]` to get `X = [[1, 1, 1, 1], 2, [3, 3], [1, 1], 4, [5, 5, 5, 5]]` this. Thank you again!

Comment: @J.Doe, I am not writing an answer since @Willem Van Onsem's answer is very helpful (and complete , +1 for that) but as a tip I think the easiest way would be to write a predicate that takes as input the list that  `pack/2` produces and just remove the lists from one-element lists and keep just elements,, this would be very easy with just a recursion...

Comment: @J.Doe: I think it is usually better to let predicates do a "limited amount of work": so you better construct one predicate that does the packing (and creates a list of lists), and one to unpack *one element lists*. Since (a) you do not have to worry about all kinds of corner cases (and edge case) making the predicate harder to write/read/understand; and (b) you now have two predicates that you can also use independently.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thank you a lot! You made it so clear for me!